# Can't clone a private GitLab repository; 403 error

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using

`git clone https://gitlab.com/project_name/repo_name.git`

and also using

`git clone https://username@gitlab.com/project_name/repo_name.git`

and both of them give the same error, as follows:

`fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/project_name/repo_name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28850867/5987698).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your ssh key into your user's profile in gitlab?  If you are using http to clone/pull/push/etc you have to authenticate if the repo has ANY restrictions on it, which it should by default, and is sane since you don't want, for example ME, going and mucking with your repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an admin, it's possible that you forgot to add yourself as a member to the private repo. You need to be a member to clone the code / run the pipeline.